# Add acceptance rate to the user profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accept-rate

Since this is really data about the person I would like it to also be available on the person's profile page.  Perhaps in the section containing their personal data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, but I need some other meaningful stats to put in there, first. It can't just be accept rate alone.

Comment: Why not follow an agile approach and put what you have there now, and add to it as you go along?

Comment: Also: see this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2563/is-the-ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-a-meaningful-measure-of-participation for more ideas.

Comment: For starters, you could add both question and answer acceptance rate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/add-an-answer-acceptance-rate-too

Comment: Here's another idea for the "stats" page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile/

Comment: The only way for a user to check on his/her accept rate at the moment is to locate one of his older posts!!

Comment: @Jeff is this feature-request dead?

Comment: @Trufa looks like that..

Comment: It seems odd that other users can find my acceptance rate more easily than I can!

Answer (score 8):

*To answer the question and to add to Jeff's post...*

To keep the inevitable support questions like *"My calculated rate is wrong"* or *"What does this percentage mean?"* to a minimum, the profile could contain the information which is used to calculate that number.

- Number of questions not community wiki
- Questions older than 3 days.
- Questions with at least 1 answer.
- ...plus # of *qualifying* questions with an accepted answer **= %accepted.**

Answer (score 5):

While I am no great fan of the accept rate itself, as long as it's with us I do agree it deserve to be in the user profile. Its natural location is below the badges:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

We need the Accept Rate in the User Profile, so that I don't have to go click on one of my questions when I want to see what it is.