# How to handle loads of rep recalc questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation-recalc, alerts

In preparation for the [soon to be implemented change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) in the rep system, and the necessary global rep-recalc and the ensuing onslaught of *WTF!?! Where did all my rep go??* questions that are bound to be asked.  What is the best way to prevent dozens of duplicate questions here on MSO?

S Mark suggested in a comment to the [original proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced) to put up an alert bar on all the sites announcing the change.  Jeff declined saying that it would just be an invitation to support requests.

I suggest toning it down a bit.  How about an alert bar only here on meta?

It can be assumed that anyone on meta already knows about the changes and recalc and will just accept the notification and continue on their way.  Any other SOFU users who come here for support will get the notification as the first then when they log into MSO and hopefully have their question answered immediately.  Perhaps the bar could point to Jeff's original question proposing the idea or the blog post announcing it.

Is there a better way to handle the hordes of questions that are imminent?

Comment: This seems like a pointless question just to get rep.  I want to cut the rep you've earned on this in in half and then make it retroactive to all of your other pointless questions...  Oh wait, there were some good ones there...

Comment: I've got to find some way of making up all that rep I'm going to loose!  The answer?  **2x pointless questions!**

Comment: Free the rep! Free the rep!

Comment: I understood his point on the declination though.

Answer (score 17):

Big orange bar on the top of the screen, "[Where did my rep go!?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/)"

Answer (score 11):

> Thank you for your ongoing contributions to Stackoverflow. We may have previously overvalued said contributions, and have recently corrected this oversight by reducing your reputation score. We hope that this will help you better understand the diminished value of your work.

Comment: Could always double every other rep number (including moderator thresholds), because we undervalued those actions, and leave question upvotes the same.

Answer (score 10):

1. Write a "rep recalculation FAQ".
2. Close all questions as duplicates of that FAQ.
3. Beer.

Comment: I think things would be more interesting if you added "0. Beer".

Comment: can we just skip steps 1 & 2 and go straight to step 3?

Comment: 4. Profit​​​​​​?

Comment: *... In fact, forget the recalc.*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010

Comment: *... and the blackjack!*

Answer (score 6):

Every user should be sent a message whenever a recalc is done on his account, letting him know about the recalc, and how much rep was lost or gain.

It's just a small matter of scripting.

Comment: Why oh why do people insist on stating how big or small a job they believe something should be? Nothing annoys me more than when a client says "How come we can't get *x* added to our report? It's just a single column! It should be 5 minutes, how come you're billing us for 2 hours?" - when they've got no idea how the reports are calculated, and that it might be a single cell in a spreadsheet but it's not a single row in the database it is in fact dozens of calculations that all add up to be the value AND IT NEEDS DEVELOPMENT AND TESTING SO DON'T TELL ME HOW "EASY" IT SHOULD BE!

Comment: @Farseeker, it's an old computing in-joke I learned in the 80's, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming

Comment: oh, right. Sorry was just having a bad day that day with a client and a dispute over the billing of a report.

Answer (score 4):

I'd cheer them up with some waffles.

[image: waffles!]
<sub>(source: [mightysweet.com](http://www.mightysweet.com/mesohungry/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/Chicken-and-Waffle-Man.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I'm so hungry right now...

Answer (score 4):

You can refer them to

- https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
- https://serverfault.com/reputation
- https://superuser.com/reputation
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

see:  [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/)

Comment: Wow, this rep-report is cool

Answer (score 0):

I agree about the alert bar only here on Meta, and would additionally suggest to show it only for users who are new to Meta or who haven't been to Meta in over *x* days. (*x*=30 ?)  You could have the "first time here? check the FAQ" bar as well as a bar saying "Are you here because you suddenly lost a lot of rep? Read this article"