# How do I know who the rolling recalc has yet happened for...?

Tags: support, reputation-recalc

I realize, per [this meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43008#43008), that a recalc is soon happening for everybody -- any way I can tell of it has *already* happened, for myself or any other user?

Looks like it may have happened for Jon Skeet -- he's 160K right now and I'm pretty sure he was around 144K earlier today (I track "half of Jon Skeet's rep" as a pragmatic watermark for "Stack Overflow Elite";-).  Mine, however, seems to still be 79.3K (so, by not dramatically changing via the recalc, it's "dropped" below the magical "half of Jon's rep" watermark;-), while, per [the rep-report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/rep-report), I should have 88.3K (above the half-of-Jon's-rep watermark again!-).  So I think my recalc hasn't happened yet.

But, how can I *tell*?  In either my own case, Jon's, and others'?  Any suggestion welcome, thanks!

Comment: No idea how they're ordering this, I have a lower user ID than Jon's but still no recalc.

Comment: @Kev: Marc explicitly did a rep calc for himself and me.

Comment: @Jon - ah gotcha.

Comment: It seems to be rolling through the sites right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will announce more on the blog on Sunday; even for the users who "have" a recalc, it's not quite right since it has bugfixes but not the +5 question dynamic.

Although it is true that for the referenced users, the question vote reduction is not going to matter a whole lot as they get the vast amount of their rep from answers anyhow.

Comment: OK, tx, can't wait for it to be Sunday (less than an hour to go, here in PDTland;-).

Answer (score 6):

Blame me. I kicked off a few manually last night. As noted this doesn't include the 5/10 q/a - but that isn't a big factor for page 1. I *believe* that the [rep-report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/rep-report) should indicate where you are currently (88341). I can do a pre-emptive recalc for you if you like.

---

Edit: to avoid confusion, I finished page 1 column 1. So of course while all of us fully understand that rep is meaningless, and would never spend any energy or even button-clicks tracking it, we now all know where (on that scale of meaningless) we sit ;-p

I've checked, and a recalc on column 2 would *not* shuffle anyone into column 1, so I've stopped there.

Comment: Thanks Marc, yep I see column 1 all renormalized now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There have been [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/how-to-handle-loads-of-rep-recalc-questions/42901#42901) [good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/how-to-handle-loads-of-rep-recalc-questions/42899#42899) [suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/how-to-handle-loads-of-rep-recalc-questions/42902#42902) [made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/how-to-handle-loads-of-rep-recalc-questions/43007#43007) to notify users after their rep has been recalculated.