# How about displaying a banner on top, that the reputation was recalculated?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, reputation-recalc

I don't know, if this would be possible (at least for next time)? I mean, probably a lot of people don't read the blog (or even meta). These banners are displayed for so many things, so - why not?

Comment: @Kop: Not everyone does. But I read them, and it would have spared me the shock. :)

Comment: My rep dropped and I (unaware of the recalc) went hunting to see where I'd been downvoted. I would have liked a banner. +1

Comment: @chris: yeah i changed my mind and deleted my comment; I think at least some people will read them

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/how-to-handle-loads-of-rep-recalc-questions

Comment: Completed for meta only

Comment: Oh, but it wasn't me who put it up - I thought jeff did and just marked it completed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I put up a banner here on Meta to try and explain the reputation situation. I figure that if they're already here on Meta, they're here to complain, so the banner should save everyone some time and frustration.

Comment: Thanks! That's better. It still assumes, that people visit meta though (what percentage is it actually? I'd guess, it's rather low (not in absolute numbers of course)?)

Comment: Can the banner be bigger? It's not helping...

Comment: It'd get read more (meaning, 10% instead of 5%) if it were up on SO, where it might catch users' eyes a little bit before they notice their reduced rep.

Comment: Moderators can do that? Cool.

Answer (score 5):

I understand the theory, but I am not sure this is a good idea, and I have opted not to do it.

That's because we'd be inviting *every* user in the system to complain about rep changes, instead of that subset of users who actually care about their rep scores.

EDIT: However, it *IS* a good idea to do it on Meta! I totally support that, so good job whichever mod just put in the banner here... (smacks self for not thinking of this)

Comment: How about display it on meta only?

Comment: Can we make a message come up before allowing them to post if they say "reputation" in their SO question?

Comment: Or a question title tip?  "You seem to be asking about lost reputation.  Have you read this blog post?"

Comment: @ceejayoz: great minds...

Comment: Well, I have joined SO just about a week ago. And when I saw the reputation drop, I first thought: I must have written something massively wrong/bad/?! I was actually - sad. Then as I didn't find, where I may have lost it, I got somewhat disillusioned about SO (a little bit doubting its quality or reliability). For a short moment, I really lost my motivation to post anything ever again. Then of course, I looked at meta and the blog, to find out what might have happened - but not everyone will...

Comment: or not make it retroactive! I think most people are fine with the change in question vote value, but most people (including me) are very upset about the sudden deductions!!!

Comment: @Jeff: excellent banner on MSO.  I think it'd suit SO very well, and counter the disenchantment that users like chris_l talk about.

Comment: @Josh - that has it's own problems

Comment: @Josh: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42885/new-reputation-changes-is-applying-it-retroactively-fair

Comment: *"smacks self for not thinking of this"* You should have videotaped that and put it on youtube.

Comment: Some users will simply be upset. Others will go through their posts trying to figure out what happened. Some will come to meta - and at least those users will see the banner. By not posting the message on SO you are creating a poor user experience.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the idea that putting a banner on the home page would invite criticism from _all_ users. It seems to me that a user that doesn't care about their rep score wouldn't care if it was recalculated, and would ignore the banner. At the very least, a notice should have gone on the **profile page on SO**. That's the first place someone would go to investigate a sudden drop in rep, so that's where the info should be. Making people jump over to meta for something this major makes for a very poor user experience.

Comment: I had originally meant one of those dynamic banners that appear *once* to logged in users, like those "You have earned the Three-Headed Monkey badge. See your profile". This would have the advantage, that they'd also see it *once*, even if they don't login in the next few days. And that non-registered users won't see it at all. And that it won't be displayed all the time.