# Reputation Status Message in SO would be useful

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about displaying a banner on top, that the reputation was recalculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43274/how-about-displaying-a-banner-on-top-that-the-reputation-was-recalculated)

The status message about StackOverflow reputation change in meta

`Reputation scoring has been revised and recalculated on all Stack Overflow family sites. Learn more about this change.`

would be really useful if it is SO also... I searched my profile `30 min` to what made this change... Then when i browsed meta i found this... If the above status message is present in SO it would have been easier for me and other users...