# Why am I regularly getting +5 from upvotes when I am nowhere close to the rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced)

On Stack Overflow, I frequently get upvoted answers that only receive a +5 upvote, even if it is the first score I receive that day.

I thought +5 only came into effect upon hitting the 200 (or whatever) daily reputation limit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not +5 on questions.

Comment: See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused by your own questions that you've posted answers on?

Answer (score 17):

[From looking at your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33604/adam?tab=reputation), those are upvotes on **QUESTIONS.**

Question upvotes are worth 5 points, and answer upvotes are worth 10.

Comment: Give this guy a gold badge!