# Badge suggestion: upvotes for valuable questions regarding a topic

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

While topic badges are awarded for up-voted answers, and there are badges awarded for single questions (nice question etc), there are no badges for upvoted questions of a specific topic. I asked myself why is that, and whether there is a place for a badge regarding that.

For example, a user asks a series of good questions regarding a specific topic (say "vectorization"), and these questions do get attention and upvotes but not enough to earn the user a single question badge. However, the overall number of up-votes for these questions was say a 100 or 400, such that the user's questions did made a significant  contribution to that topic. Or, maybe a case where the user asked more than 20 questions on a specific topic that each of them was up-voted more than 5 times, and so forth...

I think the community should consider a different kind of topic type badge for these cases.

Comment: I don't see the added value of this since tag-badges are already awarded for answers. A question doesn't necessarily contribute to a topic either if it's too local. It may still be upvoted because it's just formatted well. With answers, you are always helping out, even if it's just one person.

Comment: Your reward is having your questions answered :)

Comment: No need to delete - the idea may not have a lot of support (right now), but the discussion is still worth keeping around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately the goal of StackExchange is to provide good answers. Good questions are those which lead to good answers.

Question upvotes used to be worth 10 rep. They were later dropped to five, when we realized we wanted fewer questions and more answers - and good ones, at that.

A badge for good questions would run counter to this principle.

Comment: and then again you have the "nice question", "Favorite Question"  even gold badges for "Great Question" and "Stellar Question"...

Comment: Because we like good questions. They result in good answers. However, we want to promote people to answer more and ask less.

Comment: When it was dropped to 5, was everyone's rep recalculated, or did it just continue on differently?

Comment: @Cole I think it was recalculated. See: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced). Though I wasn't around at the time, so I'm not sure

Comment: @ColeJohnson I have confirmed this. I was curious, so I dug up [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) on the matter.