# Why Did The Amount of Rep From A Question Upvote Halved?

Tags: support, questions, up-votes

Reading a Meta.SE post (can't find it), I've discovered that the amount of rep gained from an upvote on a question you own used to be 10. But now, the amount of rep gained is now reduced to 5. I don't quite see the need to reduce the amount of rep gained other than that new users should make higher quality questions to gain more upvotes and more rep.

Can someone explain to me why the amount of rep gained from a upvote on your question has reduced from 10 to 5?

Comment: The original request that corresponds to the change is here: [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced) But the reasoning is only really explained (well) in the corresponding blog post here: [Important Reputation Rule Changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/)

Comment: If Meta isn't affected, what happened after that

Comment: @animuson The blog post also says that meta questions are still at 10, so I'm not sure if this is intended.