# Accepted answer complement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an answer acceptance rate, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/add-an-answer-acceptance-rate-too)

I think it would be great to complement the the newly added "accepted rate" feature for the questioner with a "accepted rate" feature for the answerer.

Actually I thought this was the feature all about when I saw the announcement.

Current user reputation is a very good indication of how good a user is, but it has a direct relationship with the time spent on SO ( obviously better answers require less time spent in SO. Jon Skeet reaches it's 200 limit in two answers with 10+ up votes) .

Adding the accept rate from the answer side, will also encourage in the quality of the answer.

Comment: similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/add-an-answer-acceptance-rate-too and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that these sorts of "participation metrics" should be on the user profile page, and *not* cluttering up the user info display below questions (and answers).

With much more of this, SO is going to look like all those ugly "forums" with stars and cute names and all kinds of junk under people's names. What we have is enough!

Comment: :-S :-S I'm tempted to mark yours as accepted only to increase my 60% of accepted rate oh oh

Comment: I hardly think a metric that is highly germane to the question, which appears ONLY on questions, and ONLY under specific circumstances (more than 4 questions), is worthy of this kind of reaction.