# Ratio of accepted own answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Add an answer acceptance rate, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/add-an-answer-acceptance-rate-too)
>   [Would it be useful so show people’s “hit rate” - i.e. percentage of answers accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep)

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I really couldn't find similar topic.

I would be interested to see the ratio of accepted answers, but not percent of other people's answers I have accepted, but the **percent of my answers that OPs have accepted**.

Is it available somewhere and do you think it would be useful?

Comment: Yes, this actually is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16725/add-an-answer-acceptance-rate-too-closed, which is itself a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a DataExplorer query for this here: [What is my accepted answer percentage rate](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/96/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate)

Just enter your user ID (82592) to get the percent, currently you're at 36.36%

Comment: First time I hear of odata, thanks!