# Accept Rate in User Page

Tags: discussion, user-interface, usability, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add acceptance rate to the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/add-acceptance-rate-to-the-user-profile-page)

Why isn't the acceptance rate displayed on the user page?

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/add-acceptance-rate-to-the-user-profile-page

Answer (score 1):

They figured it was only relevant when answering a question, so you only see it when doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that it'd be convenient to have it on the user page, but I can understand why it wouldn't be relevant while browsing somebody's profile.

Comment: In any case, it can be estimated from the number of questions with accepted answers listed in the profile.