# How to view your acceptance rate?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add acceptance rate to the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/add-acceptance-rate-to-the-user-profile-page)

Is there a section on your profile page to view your acceptance rate? If not it should be there.

Comment: Acceptance rate of what? Questions asked or questions answered?

Answer (score 2):

Drilldown into any of the questions you have asked and you will see your accept rate there.

It will appear only if you have atleast 4 eligible questions.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/