# What to do about mass down votes?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes)

I just got four completely unrelated down votes to both questions and answers within two minutes and obviously no comments at all. This may be a coincidence but I don't think I have ever had that many votes on different questions in such a short timespan so I am inclined to think that this is not a coincidence.

Is there any way to limit that sort of behavior? I am not so much concerned with the rep loss. I can live with that, but the value of the voting system is reduced if people start using this as a tool of vengeance (or whatever it is).

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/please-detect-serial-down-voting-and-generate-a-pop-up-and-a-limit-to-disallow-vo) seems to cover much of my concern, so I guess my question is simply: will this situation be detected and votes restored after a while? On of the answers seems to indicate that it will, but I can't seem to locate it in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, SO already does that.**

Check out [Mysterious downvotes (14 random downvotes in 5 minutes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/mysterious-downvotes-14-random-downvotes-in-5-minutes) for an example in action

If there really is someone targeting you with mass down votes then the system will catch it.  The votes will disappear, your reputation will be restored.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I shouldn't complain about measly four down votes then.