# Reputation Vendetta Timeouts

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Earlier today several of my answers got downvoted over a period of a couple of minutes in the order they are listed in my profile, which is rather unlikely to be a coincidence. Presumably someone took something I'd said personally.

Can there be a cap on the number of times a user can downvote answers by the same user in a particular time period? Something that flashes up "don't be a dick, add a comment to the question instead"

Comment: I had exactly the same thing happen to me yesterday. Seventeen answers, some a year old, were suddenly downvoted. I sent an email to team@stackoverflow.com, and before they could reply, their automated script ran and cleaned everything up.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the insult...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scripts exist caring about vote fraud. If it is not corrected automatically, flag the posts for moderator attention.

Comment: The script runs every 24 hours. Sit back and wait and the votes will go away. I used to have this happen once a week like clockwork.

Comment: Does it notify the cultprit that there a dooshbag?

Answer (score 7):

There already is, "serial downvoting" is detected, and silently nullified. See the [blog.stackoverflow.com blog post "Vote Fraud and You"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/):

> Unfortunately, for those users that do, the pattern was quite clear. As of today, we have several queries that look for unusual downvote patterns. If we discover these patterns in a given user’s voting history, we view all their downvotes for that user as suspect. They’re all silently deleted, and any lost reputation is restored to the unfortunate target of these downvotes.

Other related meta.SO questions:

- ["Please add a serial downvote tax."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/please-add-a-serial-downvote-tax)
- ["How often do people get serial down voted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/how-often-do-people-get-serial-down-voted/1795)
- ["How to deal with repeated abuse?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12406/how-to-deal-with-repeated-abuse)