# How to deal with retaliation on stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reputation Vendetta Timeouts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/reputation-vendetta-timeouts)
>   [So, what’s happening to my reputation? How do I report something fishy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy)

Recently I downgraded the incorrect answer on one of the questions. After that I lost around 30 points. Looking at my history I can tell that many of my old answers were recently (few hours ago) downgraded by 2 points. I suspect this was the user which question I downgraded. He later removed his answer.

How do you deal with such things?

Comment: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/so-whats-happening-to-my-reputation-how-do-i-report-something-fishy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you've got two options:

1). Do the childish thing and retaliate in kind. You'll lose more karma, self-respect and probably draw the ire of the mods anyway.

2). Let it slide and put your faith in the autobot and the mods to repair the damage.

Clearly one of those isn't a real option.

Fwiw I often find that when this happens some kindly passing souls will give me an upvote which of course more than compensates.